# jquery if statement with print styles returns undefined?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, undefined

I'm working on a project that makes use of a print stylesheet. I need to manipulate the DOM when a user prints the page to change the layout. (unfortunately cannot be done via aforementioned stylesheet).

After some research, I figured it would be acceptable to have jquery check if the navigation was hidden, (we have it set to `display: none;` when print styles are active) then include the DOM manipulation needed (the `font-size: 100px` was just a visual check to see if it works):

```
if ($('#topnav').is(':hidden')) {
  const headTwo = $('section div.tab-wrapper ul.nav.nav-tabs li a');
  headTwo.css('font-size', '100px');
}
```

However, when run it returns "undefined." I threw an `else` in there to test if the

```
const headTwo = $('section div.tab-wrapper ul.nav.nav-tabs li a');
headTwo.css('font-size', '100px');
```

was the problem, but it works as intended. Is there any reason that the print style for #topnav cannot be used in the statement?

Comment: Which part, exactly, is returning undefined?

Comment: @Taplar I'm not sure what you mean, this is what I see when in the console: https://imgur.com/a/ADjySfw

Comment: You are seeing that because the if statement does not have a return.  It's just one of the things your browser console does.  It tries to echo the return of any statement it runs.  If there isn't a return, it's undefined.

Comment: Ah, would I then need to write a function with the code above to have the statement return?

Comment: No, this isn't a problem.  Your script isn't going to be running in your browser console for normal users, :)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for all the help @Taplar!